# wget not working with 404 not found

Tags: wget

The same exact url has no problems downloading from chrome, but when I try with wget I get the error:

```
xxx@yyy:~/dataset/imagenet_synsets$ wget http://image-net.org/download/synset?wnid=xxx&username=xxx&accesskey=xxx&release=latest&src=stanford
[1] 5842
[2] 5843
[3] 5844
[4] 5845
[2]   Done                    username=xxx
xxx@xxx:~/dataset/imagenet_synsets$ --2017-05-12 11:11:31--  http://image-net.org/download/synset?wnid=xxx
Resolving image-net.org (image-net.org)... 171.64.68.16
Connecting to image-net.org (image-net.org)|171.64.68.16|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-05-12 11:11:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `wget` does not follow redirects. I might suggest using `curl` instead.

Use the `-L` flag to make curl follow redirects, and `-O` or `-o <filename>` to redirect output to a file:

```
curl -L -O http://image-net.org/download/synset\?wnid\=xxx\&username\=xxx\&accesskey\=xxx\&release\=latest\&src\=stanford
```

or (saving to `myfile.html`):

```
curl -L -o myfile.html http://image-net.org/download/synset\?wnid\=xxx\&username\=xxx\&accesskey\=xxx\&release\=latest\&src\=stanford
```